# Postgres already contains database in kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have a Postgres pod which has a mounted volume:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 100M
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app: postgres
  name: psql-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100M
```

The yaml contains the following:

```
volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
              name: psql-config-map-volume
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: psql-claim 
              subPath: postgres
      volumes:
        - name: psql-config-map-volume
          configMap:
            name: psql-config-map // contains an init.sql
        - name: psql-claim
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: psql-claim
```

It works well, data retain after deployment/pod deletion and redeploy.

The problem appears when I modify the init.sql.
It didn't come into effect and got this message at psql pod startup:

> PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

The pod itself starts without any error (just with the old init.sql data)

What I have tried:

1. Deleting the deployment,the pvc and pv. Then redeploy everything. Same result.
2. I searched the hostpath data but /mnt/data is empty.

What else should I try? How can I force the init.sql to launch? Where the actual old data is stored if not in the hostpath?

***edit: I have search for pg files and found this:***
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6ae2../merged/mnt/data/postgres/pg_ident.conf
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6ae2../diff/mnt/data/postgres/pg_ident.conf
And it still exists after pvc and pv deletion. How can I gracefully reset its data?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar situation. It turned out that I had a typo in my `initdb.sh` script. This results in PG starting, failing to apply the script and crashing. This causes the container to restart, and the next time, PG skips the script.

I finally figured it out because the pod was showing `restartCount: 1`. Running `kubectl logs postgres-0 --previous` gave me the logs from *before* the crash, which pointed to a typo in my script (`LC_TYPE` instead of `LC_CTYPE`, in my case).